# How access to content in dowloads folder in Android Q with contentResolver

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, mediastore

I launch an intent to go to the download folder in Android and I can select an item but I can't get the path of this item to can run it in Mediaplayer video.

I'm getting this uri in the intent:

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/29
```

And I'm trying to access to the path of the video in this way:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    fun getVideo(context: Context, urip: Uri) {
        val SELECTION_ARGS = "%29%"
        val LIKE = " like?"
        val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID)
        val selection = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + LIKE
        val selectionArgs = arrayOf(SELECTION_ARGS)

        context.contentResolver.query(
            MediaStore.Downloads.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null
        )?.use { cursor ->
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                val file = cursor.getString(0)
            }
        }
    }
```

But cursor don't have any item.

Comment: You can get the input stream of the chosen video file like this: context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri). 
Then save this stream as a file to the app cache folder and use it in the media player.

Comment: Can you provide a minimum example of this, please!

Comment: fun saveToFile(videoUri: Uri, fileName: String) {
   val file = File("${context.cacheDir}${File.separator}$fileName")
   openInputStream(videoUri).use { input ->
                val outputStream = openFileOutputStream(file)
                outputStream.use { output ->
                    val buffer = ByteArray(4 * 1024)
                    while (true) {
                        val byteCount = input.read(buffer)
                        if (byteCount < 0) break
                        output.write(buffer, 0, byteCount)
                    } output.flush()
                   } }
}

Comment: Are you using `VideoView` to load and play the video?

Comment: Mediaplayer @SamChen

Comment: Give me some errors in the code that you provide me @SergeyO

Comment: you are quering the Video.Media path, but provister lists the file in documents path. i start quering always with null values and set projection, selection and selection args later